# php failed to parse time string

Tags: php

I want to get difference between a date in db and the current date

That is my code :

```
 $current_date = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    foreach ($notifs as $notif) {
        $created_notif = new \DateTime($notif->created);
        $diff = date_diff($current_date, $created_notif);
                if ($diff->y > 0) {
                    $notif->time = $diff->y . " year";
}
//..
}
```

And this is the error that i got :

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (17/05/2016
>   08:54) at position 0 (1):

And to don't say that i havent searched i tiried `DateTime::createFromFormat`

Some thing like this :

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
            $current_date = new \DateTime(date($format));
            foreach ($notifs as $notif) {
                $created_notif =\DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$notif->created);
                $diff = date_diff($current_date, $created_notif);//line 32
 debug($created_notif);//line 33
                die();
```

That's what i got :

> Warning (2): date_diff() expects parameter 2 to be DateTimeInterface,
>   boolean given [APP/Controller\AdminController.php, line 32]
>
> \src\Controller\AdminController.php (line 33)
>
> false

Please i need your help

Comment: why **\\** as prefix of `DateTime`??

Comment: @FrayneKonok - namespacing

Comment: If i don't use it he don't know it

Comment: So what is the format of `$notif->created`? Looks like `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker.

Comment: @MarkBaker 17/05/2016 08:54 as the error message

Comment: Then @lolka_bolka has given you the correct answer below

Comment: Though if `$notif->created` is your value from the database, you'd be better off using Date/Time datatypes on the database, with their default format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: @MarkBaker t doesn't work it print the same error

Comment: As your `$notif->created` doesn't have seconds, make sure you're using a mask of `Y-m-d H:i` and not ``Y-m-d H:i:s`

Comment: @MarkBaker yes i've nnoticedthat

Comment: Doh!!! `d/m/Y H:i`; not `Y-m-d H:i`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume, the `$notif->created` is `17/05/2016 08:54` so at that point you should use

```
$created_notif = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $notif->created);
```

This is why you not get a `DateTime` object and this is why `date_diff` not works.

Comment: `var_dump($created_notif)` it should be `false`.

Comment: I changed the format as you say d/m/Y H:i and i got the same error

Comment: what you get from `var_dump($notif->created)`?

Comment: @MateiMihai '17/05/2016 08:54' 
The problem is from 
`     $format = 'd/m/Y H:i';
            $current_date = new \DateTime($format);`

Comment: @MateiMihai Thank you for fixing the misspell. What a shame :)

Comment: You don't need to pass the format when instantiating the DateTime object.. you must simply init it with `new \DateTime()`